# How to do HTTP POST request with queryParam using Jersey 2.26 client?

Tags: java, http-post, jersey-2.0, http-get, jersey-client

I am using Jersey client to do requests. Here is an example.

```
https://myschool.com/webapi/rest/student/submitJob?student={student:[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","age":20},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","age":20}]}&score={score:[{"id":1,"math":90,"art":80,"science":70},{"id":2,"math":70,"art":60,"science":80}]}
```

And the response would be like this:
{"jobId":"123456789","jobStatus":"JobSubmitted"}

This is my current code:

```
String student = {student:[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","age":20},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","age":20}]};
String score = {score:[{"id":1,"math":90,"art":80,"science":70},{"id":2,"math":70,"art":60,"science":80}]}

String responseResult = client.target("https://myschool.com/webapi/rest/student/").path("submitJob")
                        .queryParam("student", student).queryParam("score", score).request("application/json").get(String.class);
```

The problem is the real request URI is too long that I got 414 error. So I need to use POST instead of GET method. But I send the request using queryParam but not Body. Could anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is based on the inspiration from @MohammedAbdullah 's answer, as well as jersey documentation.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("https://myschool.com/webapi/rest/student/").path("submitJob");
Form form = new Form();
form.param("student", student);
form.param("score", score);
String responseResult = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE), String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use POST Method and Set Content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". POST method increases allowable url request limit.


 String student = {student:[{"id":1,"name":"Tom","age":20},{"id":2,"name":"Bob","age":20}]};
 String score = {score:[{"id":1,"math":90,"art":80,"science":70},{"id":2,"math":70,"art":60,"science":80}]};
 Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
 Form input = new Form();
 input.param("student", student);
 input.param("score", score);
 Entity<Form> entity = Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
 String url = "https://myschool.com/webapi/rest/student/submitJob";
 ClientResponse response = client.target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
.post(entity);
```

Comment: When I tried your code, there was an error of "resource(url)" in the last line of code. Maybe I had misunderstanding, Could you please explain it? @MohammedAbdullah

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: The error message: "The method resource() is undefined for the type Client". @MohammedAbdullah